# Agregar filas con registros a un formulario dinámicamente que tiene datos en un SELECT consultados a la BD

Tags: php, html, jquery

hola a todos espero que me pueda explicar mejor, tengo un formulario el cual tiene 2 select y 1 input, el primer select es llenado con los datos consultados BD al abri el formulario, el segundo tiene datos predeterminados y el input lo llena el cliente, adicional tiene un botón para agregar o copiar la fila con append() todo funciona bien al copiar la fila pero al copiar la primera fila No muestra los registros de la consulta realizada a la BD
codigo del formulario

```
    <form action="index.php?pg=registrarSalidas" method="post" >
            <div id="grupo">
                <select name="txtProd[]" class="cbxProductos" required>
<!-- este select es llenado automaticamente al abrir el form--> 
                </select>
                <select name="txtTipo[]" id="txtTipo" required>
                        <option value=""> Select Motivo Salida </option>
                        <option value="MAL ESTADO">Mal Estado</option>
                        <option value="AVERIADO">Averiado</option>
                        <option value="OTROS">Otros</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="txtCantidad" required placeholder="Cantidad" >
                <input type="button" id="adiciona" value="Más +" >
            </div>
            <input  type="submit" value="Guardar">
        </form>
```

script js para agregar la fila

```
    var cont = 1;
        $("#adiciona").click(function(){
            cont++;
            $("#grupo").append('<div id="grupo'+cont+'"  >
<select name="txtProd[]" class="cbxProductos" required></select>
<select name="txtTipo[]" id="txtTipo" required>
  <option value=""> Select Motivo Salida </option>
  <option value="MAL ESTADO">Mal Estado</option>
  <option value="AVERIADO">Averiado</option>
  <option value="OTROS">Otros</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="txtCantidad" required placeholder="Cantidad">
<input class="eliminar" id="'+cont+'" type="button" value="Menos -" ></div>');
        });
    
   $("#frmSalidasAlmacen").on("click",".eliminar",function(){
            
        var btn_id = $(this).attr("id");//obtengo el id del elemeto cliqueado
        $('#grupo'+btn_id+'').remove();//elimino el elemeto
    });
```

imagen
[image: imagen de muestra]

hola lo que quiero decir es: cuando le doy en el boton Mas+ me copia la fila donde esta el boton Menos- pero no me trae los datos consultados a la BD que tengo en el primer select

Comment: sera porque todos tienen el mismo id?

Comment: tambien pense lo mismo pero le cambie el id="cbxProductos"  por class>="cbxProductos" para que me llenara todos los select con esa clase